# How to pause a service

Tags: java, android, service

I look around but I couldn't find a strict answer.
Is it possible to pause a service? or let him wait/sleep?

Thanks.

**EDIT** for more details:
I have a button on my activity that stop/start my service.
I would like to be able to pause my service and resume him and when my activity is shutted down only then to stop my service.
So is it possible to **pause** a service?

Comment: Can you discrible your question with more details?I can't understand it.

Comment: What does your service do? Why do you need to pause it?

Comment: Why does it matters?let's assume that it's a timer counter (like a stopper) and you can stop the time(service) and resume it.

Comment: I would just use start and stopping. Android will probably keep the Service around (but stopped) and will call onStartCommand to 'resume'

Comment: I would like to keep all of the variables in my service and not reset them after the stop/start methods. that's my main reason since stop would keep them "alive"

Answer (score 0):

A service is a process running in another thread. So, to pause a service (Thread), simply do

```
Thread.sleep();
```

Check here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29

Enjoy.

Comment: And how do I "wake him up?" xD

Comment: I sense sarcasm with **Enjoy**

Comment: You need to specify a time interval in milliseconds along with `Thread.sleep();`

Comment: The pausing time is unknown, it depends when the user click the button, so how can I use this method in order to create a pause/resume system?